# How to checkout an existing project from CVS to Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, cvs

I want to checkout my project from CVS to jenkins but I am getting following error everytime I try to set up cvs configuration for my project:

```
Stack trace

    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hudson.scm.CvsRepository.<init>(CvsRepository.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.invokeConstructor(RequestImpl.java:529)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.instantiate(RequestImpl.java:784)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.access$200(RequestImpl.java:83)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl$TypePair.convertJSON(RequestImpl.java:678)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl$TypePair.convertJSON(RequestImpl.java:717)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.bindJSON(RequestImpl.java:478)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.instantiate(RequestImpl.java:778)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.access$200(RequestImpl.java:83)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl$TypePair.convertJSON(RequestImpl.java:678)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.bindJSON(RequestImpl.java:478)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.bindJSON(RequestImpl.java:474)
    at hudson.scm.CVSSCM$DescriptorImpl.newInstance(CVSSCM.java:465)
    at hudson.scm.CVSSCM$DescriptorImpl.newInstance(CVSSCM.java:407)
    at hudson.DescriptorExtensionList.newInstanceFromRadioList(DescriptorExtensionList.java:142)
    at hudson.scm.SCMS.parseSCM(SCMS.java:59)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.submit(AbstractProject.java:1802)
    at hudson.model.Project.submit(Project.java:225)
    at hudson.model.Job.doConfigSubmit(Job.java:1350)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.doConfigSubmit(AbstractProject.java:772)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(Unknown Source)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:396)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:408)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.interceptor.RequirePOST$Processor.invoke(RequirePOST.java:77)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.PreInvokeInterceptedFunction.invoke(PreInvokeInterceptedFunction.java:26)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:212)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:145)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$11.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:537)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:739)
Caused: javax.servlet.ServletException
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:789)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:870)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$4.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:282)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:739)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:870)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:668)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1655)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
    at jenkins.telemetry.impl.UserLanguages$AcceptLanguageFilter.doFilter(UserLanguages.java:128)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:135)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1340)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am new to jenkins so may be I am missing out something. Can anyone please help me out in performing correct steps to configure my project. I have added correct cvsroot, password and other required fields but not sure what am I doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this. Jenkins CVS plug-in version 2.14 is not stable so I downgraded to version 2.13 and now I am able to checkout CVS code in Jenkins. CVS plug-in versions can be found here - [https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/cvs](https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/cvs/)/

Go to Manage Jenkins -> Manage Plugins -> Advanced -> Upload plug-in(.hpi file) and restart Jenkins for effect to take place. 
Restart command : Suppose if your Jenkins url is http://localhost:8080 , then restart using this url-  http://localhost:8080/restart

(Add restart or safeRestart to your Jenkins url)